# Get the username and discrim of a member from a member object discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How would I get the username and discriminator (tag) of a member from a member object in discord.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
member.name => returns the name of member
member.discriminator => returns the tag
str(member) => returns name and tag like "Name#0000"
```

Answer (score 1):

They're in the objects attributes.

```py
member.name
member.discriminator
```

If you want the name as displayed in the server there is also `member.nick` and `member.display_name`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member